# Answer difference between two compiler

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I compiled the following code, But I got a serious problem.
When I compiled this code in visual studio 2015, It works perfectly.
However When I compile this code in Dev C++, I think it doesn't print "Yes" as an answer.

For example, when I type words like,

1. lol
2. Was it a car or a cat i saw?
3. abcdefghiihgfedcba

these inputs must return yes, but in dev c++ returns no.

Why does this problem occur?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool is_palindrome(char input[], int numOfSlots);

int main(void) {

   char text[256], fixed[256];
   cin.getline(text, sizeof(text), '\n');

   for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(text); i++) {
      text[i] = toupper(text[i]);
   }

   int j = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(text); i++) {
      if ((text[i] >= '0' && text[i] <= '9') || (text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z')) {
         fixed[j] = text[i];
         j++;
      }
   }
   fixed[j] = '\0';
   string s_fixed = fixed;

   if (is_palindrome(fixed, s_fixed.length()) == true) {
      cout << "Yes";
   }
   else {
      cout << "No";
   }
   return 0;
}

bool is_palindrome(char input[], int numOfSlots) {
   int i = 0;
   while (i < numOfSlots / 2)
   {
      if (input[i] != input[(numOfSlots - 1) - i])
         return false;
      i++;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: It would be trivially simple for you to sprinkle in some diagnostic output to see what comparisons are happening and what their answer is. This is much more efficient then posting your program and hoping others are willing to do this for you.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: if you are allowed to use `std::string` why do you use `char[]` there?

Answer (score 4):

Your program exhibits undefined behavior since you are using uninitialized data.

You have:

```
char text[256], fixed[256];
```

which are uninitialized arrays. And then you go to access them using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(text); i++) {
   text[i] = toupper(text[i]); // Accessing uninitialized array
}
```

You can fix it using couple of ways:

1. Initialize the arrays.

   ```
   char text[256] = {0}, fixed[256] = {0};
   ```
2. Access only the elements that were filled in the call to `getline`.

   ```
   size_t size = strlen(text);
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   ```

However, the better fix is to always use the second method. That way, you don't process unnecessary data.

Comment: `sizeof(text)` should be 256. You might be thinking of `strlen(text)`, which is indeed UB at this point. Yes, he should probably not iterate through the full array, but I don't think what he's doing at that point is UB.

Comment: @mah, using uninitialized variables is cause for undefined behavior.

Comment: @mah, accessing `text[i]` beyond what was filled by `getline` is cause for undefined behavior.

Comment: @mah, The call to `getline` only initialize the elements that are required to hold the input data. The rest are still uninitialized data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102266/discussion-between-mah-and-r-sahu).

Comment: @mah the whole array is not initialized. if `getline` reads 5 characters, only those 5 characters + `\0` character will be written to the buffer. All remaining 250 characters won't be initialized, and can contain random values, that are, then, placed into `fixed` buffer (2nd loop).

Comment: Initializing array will not fix programming error - using `sizeof()` instead of strlen()

Comment: I've moved this to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102266/discussion-between-mah-and-r-sahu to avoid extended comment discussion.

Comment: I've removed my comments; see the chat log to understand my enlightenment but the real UB issue with the code is the loop copying data from `text` to `fixed` without stopping when `text` has a NULL.

Comment: Better yet use a `std::string`

Answer (score 1):

using `std::string` as replacement of `strlen()` is rather strange, when you can use it much better way:

```
bool is_palindrome( const std::string &input );

int main(void) {

   std::string text;
   getline(cin,text);

   for (size_t i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
      text[i] = toupper(text[i]);
   }

   std::string fixed;
   for (size_t i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
      if ((text[i] >= '0' && text[i] <= '9') || (text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z')) {
         fixed += text[i];
      }
   }

   if (is_palindrome(fixed)) {
      cout << "Yes";
   }
   else {
      cout << "No";
   }
   return 0;
}

bool is_palindrome(const std::string &input) {
   size_t numOfSlots = input.length();
   int i = 0;
   while (i < numOfSlots / 2)
   {
      if (input[i] != input[(numOfSlots - 1) - i])
         return false;
      i++;
   }
   return true;
}
```

of course your program can be simplified but I tried to keep it close to original to show why it is better to use `std::string` instead of old style `char[]` in C++

Here simnpliefied version using `std::string` and other algos from standard libraries:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

bool is_palindrome( std::string str )
{
   if( str.empty() ) return false;
   std::transform( str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), []( char c ) { return std::toupper( c ); } );
   str.erase( std::remove_if( str.begin(), str.end(), []( char c ) { return !std::isalnum( c ); } ), str.end() );
   auto len = str.length() / 2 + 1;
   return std::string( str.begin(), std::next( str.begin(), len ) ) ==
          std::string( str.rbegin(), std::next( str.rbegin(), len ) );
}


int main()
{
   std::string text;
   std::getline( std::cin, text );

   std::cout << ( is_palindrome( text ) ? "yes" : "no" ) << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```